# How to export DISTINCT data into DISTINCT files

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `amc_info` 
WHERE department =' ( 
SELECT DISTINCT department ) 
into outfile = 'Different department'
```

I have huge data in amc_info , with different department. One department may have more than one row, total department is more than 30, now i want to export this data with department-wise file name.

Comment: You can't create multiple out file from a single query. Consider using any script to do that.

Comment: Do you have that type of script, or you can help me to derive that script.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file.txt' 
FROM `amc_info` WHERE department IN (SELECT DISTINCT department FROM `amc_info`)
```

Check out the SELECT INTO syntax too: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

If you're just trying to get the DISTINCT departments however:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department INTO OUTFILE 'file_name.txt'
FROM `amc_info`
```

Answer (score 0):

I m using perl script
Please make sure you have Perl installed and DBI, DBD modules installed

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;


my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:DBNAME;host=localhost", 'root', 'password');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select distinct(department) from amc_info");
$sth->execute();
while (my $depart= $sth->fetchrow_array()) {

    my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("select * into outfile '$depart\.txt' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' from amc_info where department='$depart'");
    $sth1->execute();
    $sth1->finish();
}

$sth->finish();
```

**Note: Change this script and add your DB NAME , username and paswword. If using remote DB server provide the Remote IP instead of localhost**

First Select is for getting your departments
Second Select is to create file for each department and post their respective department data